# Error Code: 1129 Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, centos

For the past few days, I am getting this error every morning when I tried to connect to the MySQL database using the MySQL workbench and also through some applications. So, every day I log onto the server and run the command `FLUSH HOSTS`. Then I and some machines can connect to the database and do the daily duty. The error is as follows,

> Error Code: 1129 Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' is blocked because of many
>   connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

The MySQL databases are in a server that running a Linux operating system (CentOS). Among other databases, we have a database that is using frequently.

**Database tables are as follows,**

```
|table 1     |     4000 records|
|table 2     |     2000 records|
|table 3     |     1500 records|
|table 4     |    35000 records|
```

So, the database and other tables are not working until I run the command `FLUSH HOSTS` And also I am facing some slowness in `table 4`. When I run `SELECT * FROM table 4` query in workbench sometimes it throws this error,

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

So I have increased the `maximum connections`, `net_read_timeout` and `connect_timeout` values.
`table 4` has `35000` records around `5 MB`. But I don't think the number of records is not the issue. Some of our mobile applications also throw `time out errors` because of this database issue.

And also I see

> waiting for table level lock

in each `UPDATE, INSERT and SELECT` queries when I run the command `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. And at that time `table 4` is really slow. Table Engine is `MyISAM`. Does that make any sense?

**Note:-** I have seen many questions with answers similar to this question. But they didn't help me. So before flag this as duplicate, please read the whole question.

So anybody can help me? I am really grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to see if anything changed on the server just before this error started to appear?

Comment: @raphael75 Actually I don't know much about the server. That is a VM. How can I check if any changes happen in that server?

Comment: If you can't access the server yourself, the best thing is to contact the server administrator. If you can access it, check the system logs from right before the error started happening to see if anything looks unusual.

Comment: @raphael75 What about this? `waiting for table level lock`

Comment: How often does the data change in table 4? Does it have a lot of inserts/updates/deletes at once? I had a similar issue to what you are experiencing and it occurred when a script ran that inserted hundredss of rows into various tables at once. The database was getting overwhelmed by so many inserts at once and we got the error you got. We fixed it by setting up a queuing system that would only insert 1 row at a time.

Comment: @raphael75 Yes. Sometimes it maybe once. Because we insert records (some times it may be 100+ records or less. Sometimes 5-10 records) to `db1.table4` and from that table insert same records to `db2.table4` using `insert trigger`. A mobile app will update those records in `db2.table4` and `update trigger` will update records in `db1.table4`. So some times these all actions will run at once.

Comment: So do you think this may be the problem?

Comment: It may be the problem. We tried tweaking all kinds of settings in the MySQL config, but the only thing that fixed it was to set up the queue. In our case the rows were being inserted by a PHP script, and we created another PHP script to queue up the inserts and only insert 1 at a time. As a test, you could try only inserting 1 row and see if you get the lock to see if the number of inserts is causing the locks. If it is, you could look into a queuing option.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`.  (How much RAM?)